# A simple example to practice justifying the interchange of derivative and expectation

Tags: integration, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have been self-studying probability and measure theory.  The condition I have for the interchange of derivative and integral is as follows, and comes from Folland, G. B. (1999). Real analysis: modern techniques and their applications (Vol. 40). John Wiley & Sons.

---

Let
\begin{align*}
& f : \mathcal{X} \times [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}, && \text{ where } (-\infty < a < b < \infty) \\
& f(\cdot, t) : \mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{R} \text{ be integrable} && \forall t \in [a,b] \\
&F(t) := \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x,t) \; d\mu(x)   \\
& \partial f / \partial t \quad \text{exist} \\
& \bigg|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\bigg| \leq g(x) \qquad \forall x,t \qquad \text{for some integrable} \; g
\end{align*}

Then $F$ is differentiable and
$$ F'(t) = \int_{\mathcal{X}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \; d\mu(x)   $$

---

This theorem may seem overly restrictive, since the real-valued parameter has bounded support.  However, as noted by Folland (1999) pp. 56, continuity and differentiability are *local* in nature.  Thus, if the hypotheses of (a) or (b) hold for all $[a,b] \subset I$ of an open interval $I$ (which is perhaps $\mathbb{R}$ itself), perhaps with the dominating function $g$ depending on $a$ and $b$, one obtains the continuity and differentiability of the integrated function $F$ on all of $I$!

---

Now I would like to practice using this theorem to justify the exchange of a derivative and expectation in a simple setting.    To accomplish this, I have come up with the following simple problem, which is inspired by problems in which one finds the ``best" (in a mean squared sense) predictor of a random variable.

---

Let $X$ be a random variable with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$.  Show that
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \mathbb{E}[(X-a)^2]  = \mathbb{E}[\frac{\partial}{\partial a} (X-a)^2]. $$

---

And here is my attempt at a justification.

---

We first identify a dominating function for the derivative of the integrand.

\begin{align*}
|-2 (X-a)| \leq |2X| + |2a| \leq 2 (|X| + \sup_{a \in I} |a|)
\end{align*}

where we have applied the triangle inequality, and where $I$ is some closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$.  Now we show that the dominating function is integrable:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \bigg[ |X| + \sup_{a \in I} |a| \bigg] \leq \sigma + \sup_{a \in I} |a|  < \infty
\end{align*}

where I have used that the standard deviation gives an upper bound on an expected absolute value.

---

My question:  Is my justification correct?

Comment: Looks perfect .

Comment: In that example however we can calculate $\mathbb E[(X-a)^2]=\mathbb E[X^2]-2\mathbb E[X]a+a^2$ and $\mathbb E[\partial_a(X-a)^2]=\mathbb E[-2X+2a]=-2\mathbb E[X]+2a$ and see that the derivative of the former is the latter.